# Sync files in Two Different Repos using HG

Tags: mercurial

I've got a problem when I try to sync files in two different repos. What I want to do is:

I've got 2 repos A and B, and they share some common files, suppose they lie in ***A/docs/common/*** and ***B/docs/common***. So when I write some new docs in A and I want to update it to B or vice versa.  How can I do?

I try this: I write a .hgignore in A to ignore the files I don't want to sync to B, and then try to **hg push B's repo url**. It doesn't work.

So how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading it correctly and your repository roots are above the docs directory (test: `hg root` says `/file/path` **not** `/file/path/A`) Your current soln, ignoring the files outside of docs in both repos, won't work because mercurial tracks full file paths back to root, to `A/` and `B/` are part of your file paths so they're different in different the two repos making them separate repos.

One thing you could do is use [Mercurial's sub-repository support](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos) to make docs a sub-repo that's "included" within both A and B.  Then you can push/pull docs around and the separate, different parent repos will keep track of what point on docs they've been updated to.

If I misread your original situation and A and B are just separate clones and docs is a top level directory with the same path in both repos (test: `hg root` **is** `/file/path/A` and `file/path/B`), then you've got a totally normal mercurial situation that should be working.  Just make sure you're commiting, pushing (or pulling), and updating and you should see changes migrate across.